# If a function $f$ is $L$-periodic then $f'$ has $2$ zeros in $[0,L)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, periodic-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R} $ be a differentiable and odd function. If $f$ is periodic and the (minimal) period $L>0$, then $f'$ has $2$ zeros in $[0,L)$?

For example, this occurs if we consider $f(x)=\sin(x)$, for all $x \in  \mathbb{R} $, since in this case $L=2\pi$.

This is in general true? ${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; follows immediately from Rolle's Theorem.

To elaborate: $f(0)=0$. $f$ has a root at $a$, with $0<a<L$. Then $f$ has a root at $-a$ as well, so it also has a root at $-a+L$. By Rolle's Theorem, $f'$ has a root on $(0,a)$ and on $(a,L)$.

Comment: Nice answer! And to see why there must be a root in $(0,L)$, we can actually show that $L/2$ is a root. This is because $f(L/2)=f(-L/2)$ since $f$ has period $L$, and also $f(L/2)=-f(-L/2)$ since $f$ is odd. Adding these two equations gives $2f(L/2)=0\Rightarrow f(L/2)=0$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth good observation

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth great observation! Thanks!

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Is it possible to guarantee that if $f$ is $L$-periodic and odd, then $x=0$ and $x=\frac{L}{2}$ are the only zeros of $f$ in $[0,L)$?